# What is a pseudo function in Erlang?

Tags: function, erlang

I found this in the documentation:

> To each module using records, a pseudo function is added during compilation to obtain information about records:[1](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#internal-representation-of-records)

What is a pseudo function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a function call, but it's actually inline expanded by the compiler. It doesn't exist as a function in the code.